# How to inject ViteJS envs in Nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, vite

My big aim is to deploy a React/ ViteJs via Kubernetes. My app needs credentials, which are injected via env variables, e.g. VITE_APP_TEST. I host my App via Nginx. For the first step, I try it via docker.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build # vite build

FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

What I do is to build the Dockerfile via:
`docker build -t testapp . .`

Than I start it with my env variable:
`docker run -p 80:80 -e VITE_APP_TEST=testValue testapp`

What do I expect?
As mentioned above, my React/ Vite App has an env variable. I want to set this env variable via docker run (later via Kubernetes Secrets).

What is happening right now?
When I try to call this variable in my App, it's undefined. I'm sure I call the variable in a right way, because it works when I set the variable direct in the .env file.
When I call a shell in the container and execute `echo $VITE_APP_TEST`, I see the correct value.

What I want?
I want, that the docker env variable VITE_APP_TEST=testValue will set the variable VITE_APP_TEST in the .env file from the React/ Vite App.

I don't know how to solve it and I ask for help please.

Comment: Yes, I want to deploy this in producion. We have a few other applications, which are deployed in the same way. But none of these use env variables via Kubernetes/ Docker.

Comment: Credentials sound like secrets, is that correct? I’m curious if your react/vitejjs app is a SPA.